# React routing not working, dispatcher is null

Tags: reactjs

I've implemented react routing using the react-router-dom package and following the steps in a guide, however I find myself with the following problem:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this

problem.

And also:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: dispatcher is null
> useRef React
> BrowserRouter index.tsx:248
> React 12
> workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
> flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
> performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
> js scheduler.development.js:571
> js scheduler.development.js:633
> factory react refresh:6
> ```

I've checked for versions missmatching but everything seems fine, everything using react 18.2.

Here's my code:

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**src/App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Home from './routes/main/Home.js'
import About from './routes/about/About.js';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={ <Home/> } />
        <Route path='about' element={<About/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/routes/main/Home.js**

```
import React from "react"

function Home(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is the home page</h1>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

**src/routes/about/About.js**

import React from 'react'

```
function About() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is the about page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default About
```

I've also uploaded it to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-cdn-n7lweq)

Comment: Everything works fin in the sandbox when you import the library https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-snyder-3rqpqr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what do you mean? this isn't working @KonradLinkowski

Comment: wait, this is working, just not in my browser (Firefox 105.0.3) hmmm @KonradLinkowski